# Merging similar tags [photo] and [photos]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The tags [photo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo) and [photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) refer to the same subject and should be merged.

Qs tagged [photo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo)
Qs tagged [photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been completed.

A tag synonym mapping `photo` → `photos` has been created.